# Tkinter - Key bind not responding

Tags: python, tkinter

Pressing the button itself calls the function correctly, however binding the return key does not call the function.

```
# function to call frame swapping
def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

# Submition button
submit_btn = tk.Button(frame1, 
text='Submit',command=lambda:show_frame(frame)) 
submit_btn.place(x=163, y=438, height=30, width=75)
submit_btn.bind('<Return>', show_frame(frame))
```

I've searched for similar issues but have yet to find a solution.

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of code. Post the code as text instead.

Comment: Since you placed the binding directly on the Button itself, it is only in effect when the Button already has keyboard focus.  You probably want to bind to the window instead.

Comment: @jasonharper I have tried binding it to the frame and still no result